# Ensure specific function is called last (maybe asynchronously?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the function below in the `$(document).ready(function(){})` which works well and populates lots of fields, depending on the record viewed.  The problem is, on records with LOTS of results this executes before many images on the site are loaded (including the main logo and the loading indicator).  Is there any way to ensure this code is called LAST?

```
$('.WorkstationCount').each(function (i, val) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.svc/getWorkstationCounts',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'packageid': this.id },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (function (el) {
            return function (count) {
                $(el).html(count.d);
            };
        })(this),
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            $('.Toast').html('Error Retreiving Workstation Count!');
        }
    });
});
```

I tried wrapping it in a function

```
function populateCount() { }
```

and then calling

```
window.setTimeout("populateCount", 1);
```

but then it no longer populated the data at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something to happen after all images of a page have loaded (although I don't understand why this is desirable), you can use the `window.onload` event.

```
window.onload = function() { alert("Page loaded"); }
```

Comment: I don't understand how you can't understand why this is desirable, especially since I explained it, but your solution works.  So thank you.

Comment: It's just that usually people don't care for images loading. If I have helped you, please consider accepting my answer as the answer for your question.

Comment: If data takes 30 seconds to load I want the page to look decent while it's still loading data in the background...

And I will accept your answer in another 7 minutes when SO lets me... if I remember :)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setTimeout("populateCount", 1);
```

This line is not correct.  You do not need the quotes (or `window.`).  It should just be:

```
setTimeout(populateCount, 1);
```

When a string is passed to `setTimeout`, it gets `eval`d.  It should have been `setTimeout("populateCount()", 1);`, but it's better to just pass a function to `setTimeout`.

Comment: plus, that 1 is 1 millsecond, not 1 second, and waiting 1ms probably won't help.

Comment: @Matt: True, though using 1ms (or 0) is useful because it will push this function to the end of the JavaScript stack.  It may actually execute later than 1ms.  I'm not too sure how the delays work, but they are not exact.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight on this, but I believe the other answer is a better solution and more what I really want.  Thanks.

Comment: @Scott: I agree, just throwing this out there :-)